# Why can't I import `std::assert` via `use` while it works for other macros from std?

Tags: rust, macros

With Rust 2018, this code works ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=043365f406a0b110d4084fee3ed016c0)):

```rust
use std::panic;
use std::format;
use std::assert_eq;
```

But this:

```rust
use std::assert;
```

Results in this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `std::assert`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use std::assert;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ no `assert` in the root
```

I read [the edition guide about this topic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/macros/macro-changes.html) and it says that `use` should work with `macro_rules!` macros and procedural macros. Thus, I'm confused.

Comment: Educated guess: because it's annotated with [`rustc_doc_only_macro`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/macros.rs.html#933).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `use` should work with `macro_rules!` macros and procedural macros

Except `assert` is [neither of those](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libstd/macros.rs#L412-L418):

> ```
> /// Built-in macros to the compiler itself.
> ///
> /// These macros do not have any corresponding definition with a `macro_rules!`
> /// macro, but are documented here. Their implementations can be found hardcoded
> /// into libsyntax itself.
> ```

It is a [compiler built-in](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libstd/macros.rs#L932-L938):

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
#[rustc_doc_only_macro]
macro_rules! assert {
    ($cond:expr) => ({ /* compiler built-in */ });
    ($cond:expr,) => ({ /* compiler built-in */ });
    ($cond:expr, $($arg:tt)+) => ({ /* compiler built-in */ });
}
```

Other faux-macros include:

- `compile_error`
- `format_args`
- `env`
- `option_env`
- `concat_idents`
- `concat`
- `line`
- `column`
- `file`
- `stringify`
- `include_str`
- `include_bytes`
- `module_path`
- `cfg`
- `include`

The actual definition of `assert` is buried much lower in [libsyntax_ext/assert.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.33.0/src/libsyntax_ext/assert.rs)

---

[Stabilize uniform paths on Rust 2018 (#56417)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/56417#issue-386483340) does mention these in passing:

> Built-in macros, for example `use env`.
>   Currently an error due to some (fixable) implementation details of built-in macros.
>   No known issues to resolve before stabilization (after the error is removed).

Comment: But this is not documented, https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert.html clearly show `macro_rules! assert {` without any mention of compiler magic. So as a user point of view `assert` is a `macro_rules`

Comment: Mhhh. Now I have two more questions: is it intended that users can in fact not `use` that macro? And: why does `assert!` has to be a special hardcoded macro? I can understand that for stuff like `include_bytes!()` it's necessary, but `assert!`? Well, but I guess those additional questions are out of scope for your answer? :/ (PS: I also I agree with Stargateur that the docs are not optimal)

Comment: @Stargateur that's true. I'd assume that the intent is that such a built-in is *supposed* to be indistinguishable from a normal macro. This may simply be an oversight on the implementation side.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I think a recent edit addresses "is it intended" (it's a known limitation, but not desired). `assert` may just be a hold-over from early Rust development — try and rewrite it and submit a PR ^_^

Comment: It's really weird that `assert!` needs to be a built-in. It even expends to `panic!`.

Comment: [This PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/63056) sounds like it could change something about the current situation. However, I still cannot `use std::assert` on nightly, so I might be misunderstanding something.